# Index on only the right part of column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing

In an InnoDB table, there is a `varchar` column and I want to have a search query only on the last 10 characters.  When I create an index on the entire column and do the search   `where right(mycol, 10) = p_search`,  the index is not used.  Is there a way to create index such that a search query on the last 10 characters uses the index?  I understand MySQL provides creating index on the left portion, but that doesn't work in this situation.

Comment: Create a second column, copy the last 10 characters, index that column instead of the first one?  Of course all code that alters column 1 must also update column 2.

Comment: If you don't have 5.7, there is a kludge using `REVERSE()`, if anyone is interested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using MySQL 5.7 you can add a generated column that contains the right side of the column and index that.

```
ALTER TABLE yourTable 
    ADD newCol CHAR(10) AS (RIGHT(oldCol, 10)) STORED,
    ADD INDEX (newCol);
```

Note that you don't have to change your queries to use the virtual column. The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) says:

> If a generated column is indexed, the optimizer recognizes query expressions that match the column definition and uses indexes from the column as appropriate during query execution, even if a query does not refer to the column directly by name.

So if you write `WHERE RIGHT(oldCol, 10) = "abcdefghij"`, the optimizer treats it like `WHERE newCol = "abcdefghij"` and uses the index.

If you're using an older version, you can add this as a real column, and use a trigger to update it whenever the column changes (this is essentially what a `STORED` virtual column does automatically). But in this case you'll need to change your queries to test the new column.

Comment: is there Alter Table Add Column to do this?  I don't want to drop table. Tried this but syntax error. `ALTER TABLE mytable ADD right10 AS (RIGHT(mycol, 10)) STORED;`

Comment: I made a mistake, there needs to be a data type before `AS (RIGHT(mycol, 10)) STORED`. It works with ALTER TABLE.